# what version of GWT is Vaadin 7.4/7.5 based on?

Tags: gwt, vaadin7

What version of GWT is Vaadin 7.4/7.5 based on?

I know vaadin includes their own version of GWT with some addons and possible additional bug fixes but what version is vaadin 7.4/7.5 based on?

Surely you need to know this if you intend to switch from GWT jars to vaadin provided jars. For example GWT RPC does not work in development mode when you use GWT jars on the client and vaadin jars on the server even when vaadin is based on the same version of GWT. e.g Vaadin 7.1 which I believe is based on GWT 2.5.1

We have a GWT application that uses RPC and also a Vaadin application. We've had to make sure the vaadin gwt version and the gwt application use the same version of GWT (if you know what I mean).

We want to move to vaadin 7.4/7.5 so I am assuming we will need to migrate our GWT application to the same version vaadin 7.4/7.5 is based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say 2.7 with some changes for vaadin. 
I can't say for sure, but my assumptions are based on the property

```
gwt.version=2.7.0.vaadin3
```

in this file: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/7.5/build.properties

Here the same file fore vaadin 7.4: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/7.4/build.properties